# AndroidStudio endless 'Scanning files to index...'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, native-activity

I've faced an issue that AndroidStudio has a problem with indexing files that are in the NDK package. So, for example, if we take the standard AndroidStudio example of the NativeActivity (code is also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/tree/master/native-activity)) and activate files indexing (for example by clicking `Build->Refresh C++ Projects`) we obtain endless `Scanning files to index...`

It seems that AndroidStudio does not like the paths where `native_app_glue` stuff is located, from [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/tree/master/native-activity/app/src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt) from mentioned example:

```
add_library(native_app_glue STATIC
    ${ANDROID_NDK}/sources/android/native_app_glue/android_native_app_glue.c)
...
target_include_directories(native-activity PRIVATE
    ${ANDROID_NDK}/sources/android/native_app_glue)
```

In my case `${ANDROID_NDK}` is `/home/nikolay/Projects/Android/AS/Sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147`

Nothing helps, no AndroidStudio restart (after restarting AndroidStudio is stuck on `Loading project...`), no `File->Invalidate Caches/Restart`, no deleting `.gradle, .idea, app/.cxx, app/build` folders, no applying [Inotify Watches Limit](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Inotify+Watches+Limit).

But only copying `native_app_glue` sources to place without `21.3.6528147` in path, adapting CMake accordingly:

```
add_library(native_app_glue STATIC
    native_app_glue/android_native_app_glue.c)
...
target_include_directories(native-activity PRIVATE
    native_app_glue)
```

deleting `.gradle, .idea, app/.cxx, app/build` folders and restart AndroidStudio.

Has anyone faced such an issue or maybe the problem is only in my place? Thanks a lot for any help.

**P.S.:** Used AndroidStudio is 4.1

Comment: Hi, this is a known issue in Android Studio 4.1 and the team is working on a fix. See https://b.corp.google.com/issues/171801044. In the mean time, you can copy the native_app_glue.c inside your project to workaround it for now.

Comment: Hi @protossor, thank you for confirming that issue does really exist. About copying ```native_app_glue.c```, yes as I mentioned in the description, only this helped.
Regarding the link provided, unfortunately this is probably a restricted resource and I have no permission to enter it.

Comment: Ah my bad! You can see the issue with https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/171801044.

Comment: Thanks, added this link to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was figured out that it is a known issue in Android Studio 4.1 (thanks @protossor for confirming) and currently under fixing: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/171801044

So, it only remains to wait for a new Android Studio release to check whether the problem is fixed or not (results will be shared).